# Launchctl says plist is invalid, plutil says it's OK

Tags: macos, bash, launchd, plist, xml

I'm trying to have launchd run a shell script when I join a new WiFi network. I've created this plist file (closely based on [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/626919/398148)) at `/Users/myname/Library/LaunchAgents/my.networkChangeListener.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" \
 "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>my.networkChangeListener</string>
  <key>LowPriorityIO</key>
  <true/>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
<string>/Users/myname/bin/networkChangeListener/onNetworkChange.sh</string>
  </array>
  <key>WatchPaths</key>
  <array>
    <string>/etc/resolv.conf</string>
    <string>/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/NetworkInterfaces.plist</string>
    <string>/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences.plist</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

My user is the owner of the plist, and the group is "staff".

When I try to load the file by running `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/my.networkChangeListener.plist`, I get an error saying "Invalid property list".

However, when I run `plutil ~/Library/LaunchAgents/my.networkChangeListener.plist`, it returns "OK"

What is the problem with my plist file? Is is something specific to launchd? I'm completely at a dead end for how to debug this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first few lines should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
```

Your file (as well as the one in the linked answer) is missing the `<plist version="1.0">` part.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem. It does seem like something `plutil` should have caught … but then, it also seems like something I should have caught in the oodles of times I read over the code looking for mismatched tags.

Comment: Just as a hint: OS X comes with xmllint, which is part of the OpenSource libxml. If you just want to validate xml, you could try this:

`endor-3:~ garex$ xmllint /tmp/my.networkChangeListener.plist
/tmp/my.networkChangeListener.plist:21: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
</plist>
^`

That showed that your plist tag was closed but not opened...

Answer (score 0):

A totally blank plist looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict/>
</plist>
```

I use PlistEdit Pro when having to do a lot of changes, as it is easy to make mistakes.