# .plist returns: Invalid property list, plutil says ok!

Tags: macos, terminal, ssh, launchd, plist

I'm trying to create my first .plist. I want to mount a ssh drive on login so i don't have to enter the command each time I start my Mac!

The command is: `sshfs -o allow_other,defer_permissions user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/user/ /Users/user/Desktop/Website/ -o reconnect`

The plist looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple$
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>name.plist</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/usr/local/bin/sshfs</string>
                <string>-o allow_other,defer_permissions</string>
                <string>user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/user</string>
                <string>/mnt/User</string>
                <string>-o reconnect,volname=User</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've followed a tutorial saying when done with the .plist I have to run these 2 commands:

```
launchctl load ~/path/name.plist
launchctl start ~/path/.name.plist
```

It then returns `Invalid property list`

I saw [Launchctl says plist is invalid, plutil says it's OK](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181106/launchctl-says-plist-is-invalid-plutil-says-its-ok), where it says i should replace the first few lines but no change? 
*plutil* return ok when run so I'm lost!

P.S.

I've used the [template](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) below posted by user3439894. This time it loads properly but when I start it nothing happens

When I look at the systemlog there is nothing posted about it....

About the path to sshfs i've tried 2 things:

1. I've left it as it stood in the example given below.
2. I've done a suggested and added the path again /usr/local/bin/sshfs

Comment: You are concentrating on the file format not the process you are doing. You should look at documentation for LaunchAgents e.g. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html  Also does the tutorial say what path to use

Answer (score 1):

Because it would be more difficult to post this in a comment I'm posting it as an answer, although it may not be the right one.

I took your *command line* while using [Lingon X](https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) to create the *.plist* file, here is how it parsed the *command line*, which is different from yours.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>name</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sshfs</string>
        <string>-o</string>
        <string>allow_other,defer_permissions</string>
        <string>user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/user/</string>
        <string>/Users/user/Desktop/Website/</string>
        <string>-o</string>
        <string>reconnect</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

---

You'll note that while I used the *command line* you have in your question it didn't include the path to `sshfs`, you might have to add that back. The other thing it did different is each *string* in the *array* holds the information up to but not including the spaces between the arguments.  Maybe this makes a difference.  Can't say since I can't test your *command line* however it's worth a try using the format Lingon X created.

Comment: Ty for your answer user3439894 i've updated my question could you please take a look at it and tell if something comes to mind from that?

Comment: @user297239, In Terminal, does the _command line_ execute without any user input? In other words, if you type or copy & paste the full _command line_, with the _real_ information, and press _enter_... does the _prompt_ return without anything other then pressing _enter_? If yes, then I'd try running this in _application script_ form as either an Automator, AppleScript or Platypus application as a Login Item from System Preferences > Users & Groups > Current User > Login Items, then see if using a different method of execution works over doing so as a Launch Agent/Daemon using a _.plist_ file.